# SQL developer query results to dynamic csv file

Tags: oracle, export-to-csv

I am trying to export my query results to csv file with spool command in SQL Developer. It works when csv file name is static, but now I need to create file name dynamically and I tried as follow but obviously its not working. Can anyone please help?

```
var CatCode char(5) ;
exec :CatCode := 'ZK';
exec :csvFile := 'c:\temp\MyCSV_' ||  trim(:CatCode) || '.csv';    
set feedback off;
SET SQLFORMAT csv;
spool csvFile
SELECT * FROM Products WHERE CategoryCode = :CatCode;
spool off;
SET SQLFORMAT;
set feedback on;
```

I tried spool command with spool :csvFile or spool &csvFile but did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
VAR CatCode CHAR ( 5 );
EXEC :CatCode := 'ZK';
SET FEEDBACK OFF;
SET SQLFORMAT csv;
SET TERMOUT OFF

column filename new_value filename
SELECT 'c:\temp\MyCSV_' ||  trim(:CatCode) || '.csv' as filename FROM DUAL;

SPOOL &filename

SELECT * FROM Products WHERE CategoryCode = :CatCode;

SPOOL OFF;
SET SQLFORMAT;
SET FEEDBACK ON;
```

Also you might want to check this askTOM article.

https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:3581757800346555562

Comment: Thanks a lot! that's exactly I was looking for. Is there anyway to disable scripts output while exporting to csv? I just want to display message "exporting results to file..." but I dont want to display all rows in script output window.

Comment: You already have SET TERMOUT OFF in this script. That should disable the script output to window. Are you seeing the results in the window?

Comment: Yes I do see output even though I have TERMOUT OFF. What I ended up doing is, I created another script and called it with & and it worked :)